# Javascript OOP new object

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, dojo

**** EDIT *****
using the answer bellow I have created a new function and put my object into it's prototype.

```
var mySlider = new Slider();
mySlider.init({.......})
```

but now when I try to call another function from within a function (this.animate) on my Slider.prototype all I get is

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

cant seem to work out how to call get other functions to work, I've amended my code bellow with my new code

*****/ EDIT *****

I've tried to create my own slider using dojo.

I have an HTML page with the content and at the end of the page I have a script to start my slider

```
dojo.ready(function () {
var mySlider = new Slider();
    mySlider.init({
        frameId: "#sliderFrame",
        slideClass: ".slide",
        sliderImgClass: ".sliderImage",
        captionClass: ".caption",
        thumbsClass: ".thumb",
        seconds: 1
    });
});
```

then on my external js file I have my code

```
function Slider() {}

Slider.prototype = {
//Initialize all Elements
init: function (object) {
    this.sliderFrame = dojo.query(object.frameId);
    this.slideContainers = this.sliderFrame.query(".slide");
    this.slideImg = this.sliderFrame.query(object.sliderImgClass) || '';
    this.SlideCaption = this.sliderFrame.query(object.captionClass) || '';
    this.thumbs = this.sliderFrame.query(object.thumbsClass) || '';
    this.numOfSlides = this.slideImg.length || 0;
    this.hovering = false;
    this.time = object.seconds * 1000 || 3000;
    this.myInterval = '';
    this.playing = 0;
    this.start();
},
// Starts animation on slide 0
start: function () {
    this.animate(this.playing);
    this.initLoop(true);
    this.listener(this.thumbs, this.sliderFrame);
},

//EventListener for mouse events
listener: function (theThumb, theFrame) {
    theThumb.connect('onclick', this.clicked);
    theFrame.connect('mouseenter', this.mouseOn);
    theFrame.connect('mouseleave', this.mouseOff);
},
mouseOn: function () {
    this.initLoop(false);
},

mouseOff: function () {
    this.initLoop(true);
},

clicked: function (e) {
    this.playing = this.getAttribute("data-slide");
    this.animate(this.playing);
},


// start interval if true, otherwise clear
initLoop: function (act) {

    if (act === true) {
        this.myInterval = setInterval(this.loopSlides, this.time);
    } else {
        clearInterval(this.myInterval);
    }
},
// interval resets loops through to end and back to zero

loopSlides: function () {
    if (this.playing < this.numOfSlides - 1) {
        this.playing++;
        this.animate(this.playing);
    } else {
        this.playing = 0;
        this.animate(this.playing);
    }
},

//the animation which makes changes css to active slide 'e' || this.playing
animate: function (e) {

    for (var ii = 0; ii < this.numOfSlides; ii++) {
        this.slideContainers[ii].className = "slide";
        this.thumbs[ii].className = "thumb";
        this.slideImg[ii].className = "sliderImage";
        this.SlideCaption[ii].className = "caption";
    }
    this.slideContainers[e].className = "slide active";
    this.thumbs[e].className = "thumb active";
    this.slideImg[e].className = "sliderImage active";
    this.SlideCaption[e].className = "caption active";
}

};
```

The object works fine by it self and everything does as need be, I'm sure I could make it better.

What I'd like to do is have the mySlider set up with a "new" or "Object.create".
This is so I can have multiple Sliders on one page each becoming their own object.

I just can't get my script to run once I implement "new" or "Object.create" as my Slider needs to be a function not an object! :(

Cn anyone point me to a good pattern that I could use to implement what I'm trying to do.
I've gone through "essential js design patterns" but can't seem to find a pattern that fits.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Without Object.create()--just so you can understand instances--you would do:

```js
function Slider() {};
Slider.prototype = {
  init: function() {...}
  // ...
};
  
var mySlider = new Slider();
mySlider.init(...);
```

Then inside the functions just be sure to use "this.whatever" instead of "Slider.whatever".

This is essentially the same effect as using Object.create().

Comment: No! If you use a constructor, you would not use an `init` method any more. Move the initialisation statements in the constructor!

Comment: You may want to call this.init() in the constructor, but leaving it as a separate function allows you to have more flexibility when you create a subclass or mixin. See the Object.create subclassing example on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: What do you mean by "flexibility"? There's hardly a difference between using `Slider.call(this, …)` and `Slider.prototype.init.call(this, …)` - except the unnecessary verbosity.

Comment: Thank you that works great but now I'm struggling with my "this.playing" array as I used it through out various functions but it keeps console.log as "undefined". what would be the best way to parse this.play through out my object?

Thanks for the help so far much appreciated

Comment: after more experimenting looks like I'm unable to call other functions within my prototype object. I've written an update on the question which is a little more in depth :)

Answer (score 0):

oop in javascript is ugly. (at least until ES6 which supports the class and implements keywords) but even ES6 will not support multiple inheritance. I wrote [a small class library (available on github)](https://github.com/digital-synapse/ds.oop) for javascript that makes creating classes and inheritance much easier to both develop and maintain. for example to create a class just do this:

```
ds.make.class({
    type: 'a',
    constructor: function (x) { this.val = x; },
    mul: function (s) {
        this.val *= s;
        return this;
    }
});

// now to inherit class a just do this...
ds.make.class({
    type: 'b',
    inherits: a,              
    constructor: function (x) { this.val = x; },
    sub: function (s) {
        this.val -= s;
        return this;
    }
});
var o = new b(5);
var output = o.mul(3).sub(5).val;    // output = 10
```